# date between validation using PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, validation, date, between

I am having a table which has the fields: `staff_id`, `leave_applied_from`, `leave_applied_to`.

```
+----------+--------------+------------+
| staff_id | applied_from | applied_to |
+----------+--------------+------------+
|     1    | 2012-06-21   | 2012-06-21 |
|     2    | 2012-06-21   | 2012-06-23 |
+----------+--------------+------------+
```

So the requirement is, If the staff_id `1` tries to enter the date `2012-06-21` it should not allow to enter it, if staff_id `2` tries to enter the date `2012-06-22` it should not allow the staff to enter.

I know how to show errors in PHP side, but I don't know how to check the database whether the date is there in the DB, I don't know how to check both the fields in one single MySQL query.

The query should check for staff_id first and then both the other fields(applied_from, applied_to). If the staff has entered the same date range already it should give error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below:

```
SELECT * from tbl where (applied_from =< @inputdate AND applied_to >= @inputdate) 
AND staff_id=@inputid
```

If the query returns record, that means the key in date is within range and you could prompt error.

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when curdate() < applied_from or curdate() > applied_to
            then 1
            else 0
            end as is_staff_id_ok
from your_table
where staff_id = 1
```